# What's the meaning of $\alpha$ in this derivation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I'm doing a derivation related to quantum mechanics. I need to know what's the meaning of $\alpha$ in this. Here is the pdf version of the [document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t0FT14bvVyWO-rfL5P9V7OPNLT46mXfo).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t0FT14bvVyWO-rfL5P9V7OPNLT46mXfo

Comment: I'm closing this post (v2), since after the link dies, the current post is not going to be useful for anyone. To reopen, consider to make the post self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is just the name the generic quantum state you're considering to construct the Path Integral representation. Then, in the subsequent lines it is thrown away by inserting a sum over the system eigenstates, and you ends just with the sum over the projections of them over it in order to define the wave-function in the position space.